# Do foreach on a object in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do i perform foreach on a object . I wish to format the result that i get in my ci query

```
foreach ($CIResult as $key => $value) {
    $CIResult -> $key = MyCustomFunction($value);
}
```

**EDIT**

I want CIResult to stay as a object only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($CIResult as $key => &$value) {
    $value = MyCustomFunction($value);
}
```

It's important to note that this will only work on public properties of your object.

Comment: Yes it will, try it to confirm though.

Answer (score 0):

You can always [cast an object to an array](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
foreach ($CIResult as $ciObj) {
    // Access object properties like  
     $ciObj->property_name = format_name($ciObj->property_name);
}
```

Can you please, be more explicit on what you want to format ?

Comment: no i want to format the result that i got. Not just access but modify it

Comment: Format it how, and store it where ?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($CIResult as &$object) //by reference
{
     $object->property = $new_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach((array)$CIResult as $key => $value)
    $CIResult->$key = MyCustomFunction($value);
```